# Flutter - Show empty state with SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter

I'm using `SliverAppBar` and `SliverLsit` that's wrapped in a `CustomScrollView`. When there's no shops, I want to show an empty screen underneath the `SilverAppBar`. Is there a good way to do this? My work around solution is to basically show a different AppBar and screen, but it feels quite hacky and involves a lot of code.

EDIT: Also, the `RefreshIndictor` widget doesn't work for the empty state with the below impl.

```
class ListPageSliver extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SearchViewModel model = Provider.of<SearchViewModel>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        displacement: 22,
        onRefresh: () {
          return model.onRefreshList();
        },
        child: model.shops.isEmpty
            ? Column(
                children: [
                  AppBar(title: SearchBar()),
                  SearchActions(),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: NNMessagePage(
                        MESSAGE_NO_SHOPS,
                        actionText: BUTTON_ADD_SHOP,
                        onAction: () {
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, myShopsRoute);
                        },
                      )
                    )
                  )
                ],
              )
            : CustomScrollView(
                slivers: [
                  SliverAppBar(
                    backgroundColor: Color(PRIMARY_LIGHT),
                    title: SearchBar(),
                    pinned: false,
                    floating: true,
                    expandedHeight: 186,
                    flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                      background: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 82),
                        child: Container(color: Color(PRIMARY_LIGHT), child: SearchActions()),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return ShopItem(model.shops[index], model.userLocation);
                      },
                      childCount: model.shops.length,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the whole code of your Scaffold. Cutting off in the middle of Widgets makes it difficult for anyone to debug.

Comment: Sorry! I just updated the code to include the whole widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a slivertoboxadapter with empty container

```
class ListPageSliver extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SearchViewModel model = Provider.of<SearchViewModel>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        displacement: 22,
        onRefresh: () {
          return model.onRefreshList();
        },
        child: CustomScrollView(
                slivers: [
                  model.shops.isEmpty ?
                    SliverToBoxAdapter( child: Container() )
                  : SliverAppBar(
                    backgroundColor: Color(PRIMARY_LIGHT),
                    title: SearchBar(),
                    pinned: false,
                    floating: true,
                    expandedHeight: 186,
                    flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                      background: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 82),
                        child: Container(color: Color(PRIMARY_LIGHT), child: SearchActions()),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return ShopItem(model.shops[index], model.userLocation);
                      },
                      childCount: model.shops.length,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```